# how to display rows content in texview in android studio sqlite db

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm using android studio 3 and SQLite database. I have a **transactions** table. I'm trying to display some of the rows of this table using where clause in a textview. The **transactions** table has **t_id, email, bank_name, added, sent, received** and **balance** as columns. From this table i want to display only those records where **email is activeuser** and **added is not null**. I'm having **DatabaseHelper** class and a **MainActivity**. I'm calling a method from **MainActivity** to take records from tables in **DatabaseHelper**. I'm able to fetch all such records from the table(I know this because I'm getting it displayed in logcat) but not able to display each one of them in the textview. Only the last record gets displayed in the textview.
Following is the **DatabaseHelper** class code:

```
    public Cursor added(String activeuser) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            return db.rawQuery("select t_id,email,bank_name,money_added from transactions where email=? and money_added is not null", new String[]{activeuser});
}
```

**MainActivity**.java file code:

```
Cursor csr=db.added(activeuser);
                Log.d("CURSORINFO","Number of rows extracted is " + String.valueOf(csr.getCount()));
                while (csr.moveToNext()) {
                    Log.d("CURSORINFO",
                            "Row " + String.valueOf(csr.getPosition() + 1) +
                                    " ID :" + String.valueOf(csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex("t_id"))) +
                                    " Email :" + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("email")) +
                                    "Added :" +csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex("money_added")) +
                                    " Bank Name :-" + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("bank_name"))
                    );
                    t3.setText("TRANSACTION ID : "+String.valueOf(csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex("t_id")))+"\nEMAIL ID : "+csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("email"))+"\nBANK NAME : "+csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("bank_name"))+"\nMONEY ADDED : "+csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex("money_added"))+"\nSuccessfully added");
                }
```

How can i display each record where **email is activeuser** and **added is not null** in the textview. what changes need to be done?

Comment: Can you try to add textview dynamically everytime in the while loop?

Comment: That's because of your `t3.setText` inside while loop overriding previous text from the `TextView` and setting a new text.

Comment: so what changes can i make so that while loop doesnot override previous text? can you write the code?? @Kunu

Comment: How do you want to show inside one TextView?

Comment: there is only one textview, in that same textview i want to display the table record. any method to do this? @ChinmayGhag

Comment: i want to display the each record in a new line in the same textview. Currently only record is displaying @Kunu

Comment: The answer mentioned below will work for your purpose then. Get a string "Result" and append value to the string and outside while loop set the value of "Result" to textview

Comment: Have a newline at the end of every append

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to Pervez's answer.
If you want to have a same text view with every record on new line you might do this.

```
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    while (csr.moveToNext()) {
         result.append("Row " +String.valueOf(csr.getPosition()+1));
         result.append("ID:"+String.valueOf(csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex("t_id")));
result.append(" Email :" + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("email"));
result.append("Added :" +csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex("money_added"));
result.append("Bank Name :-" + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("bank_name"));
result.append("\n");

    }
    t3.setText(result.toString());
```

Comment: yeah now I'm getting the correct result. your code was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are getting more then one record but with this code but right now you are iterating our the cursor but not storing the concatenated value any where. Change this:

```
String result = "";

while (csr.moveToNext()) {
     result +=  "Row " + String.valueOf(csr.getPosition() + 1) +
                                " ID :" + String.valueOf(csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex("t_id"))) +
                                " Email :" + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("email")) +
                                "Added :" +csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex("money_added")) +
                                " Bank Name :-" + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("bank_name");
}
t3.setText(result);
}
```

Comment: the code is working as it was expected. it was helpful.